# xlwings error message when clicking on "Run main" button for quickstart script

Tags: python, xlwings

I have installed all xlwings packages and created a new project using the

```
xlwings quickstart demo4
```

line in my terminal (note that I have a Mac).
I tried to run the demo4.py file that gets created in the demo4 folder by clicking on the Run main button, but I get the following error message:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demo4'"

The output should be "Hello world" in cell A1, but it does not seem to be working. The python code looks like this:

```
import xlwings as xw


def main():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    sheet = wb.sheets[0]
    if sheet["A1"].value == "Hello xlwings!":
        sheet["A1"].value = "Bye xlwings!"
    else:
        sheet["A1"].value = "Hello xlwings!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xw.Book("demo4.xlsm").set_mock_caller()
    main()
```

The VBA code like this:

```
Sub SampleCall()
    mymodule = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
    RunPython "import " & mymodule & ";" & mymodule & ".main()"
End Sub
```

Comment: When running that macro, which basically should run the python script mentioned above, I receive the following error message: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demo4'